# Responce from anddroid and php api is correct while data is not deleting while deleting through android App?

Tags: php, android, api, android-volley

Product records not being deleting from database while pressing delete button on android app.... whereas its response is same in android as in Api's ..Api response is checked through POSTMAN software is correct and is deleting the record from database.

**Android code:**

```
case R.id.delete:
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getResources().getString(R.string.Delete_URL) + "?action=deleteProduct&product_id=" + menuItem.getItemId() + "", new Response.Listener < String > () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                if (error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error=>" + jsonObject.getString("error_message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonObject.getString("success_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage() + "<==Error Connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(request);


    break;

    }
    return false;
}
});
}
});
mProductListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**php code**

```
case 'deleteProduct':
    if(isset($_GET['product_id'])){
        $ID=$_GET['product_id'];
        $query="DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `product_id`='$ID'";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
            $response['error']=false;
            $response['success_msg']='Product Deleted successfully';

        }else{
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['error_message']='Product not exist';
        }
        }else{
            echo 'some worng';
        }
    break;
```

Comment: are you sure if `menuItem.getItemId()` returns the product id?
you can evaluate the query string at server or confirm it at android side before request is made.

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.Delete_URL) this contains root url ?

Comment: @Shahadat Hossain Shaki ............ yes sir this contains the root url

Comment: then debug the response ... with everything, Like you are sending valid params. then what is the response.. failed or success. if failed what is the reason. everything should be there ..

Comment: @ShahadatHossainShaki by debuging the android code the response is correct according to my api....and api is checked through postman tha gives the correct answer....... i think something wrong in ma android code

Comment: thats why i ask you to debug .. where your request end up? onResponse or onErrorResponse ?

Comment: @ShahadatHossainShaki                                                                                request ends up onResponse..................thiis is debug result responce    
         {"error":false,"success_msg":"Product Deleted successfully"}

Comment: that means your request is successful .. so problem maybe on server site ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code at php side:

```
case 'deleteProduct':
    if(isset($_GET['product_id'])){
        $ID=$_GET['product_id'];
        $query="DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id='".$ID."'";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
            $response['error']=false;
            $response['success_msg']='Product Deleted successfully';
        }
        else{
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['error_message']='Product not exist';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'some worng';
    }
break;
```

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: can you confirm if product ID is being sent to server?